# Trying to find minimum value from a group by SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm very nearly there with this query (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
Select selectedicao, selectedyear, selectedmonth
From weatherdaily
Where Selectedyear = 1990 and selectedmonth = 1
Group By selectedicao, selectedyear, selectedmonth
```

Output:

```
selectedicao    selectedyear    selectedmonth
-------------------------------------------------
KPKB            1990            1
KORD            1990            1
KFWA            1990            1
KCDW            1990            1
KFDY            1990            1
KLCK            1990            1
```

I just need to add the Max value in another column called `kfactor`.

This column has hundreds of values for each of these groups and I can't get a single value to be listed for each group in the above query.

Comment: Title indicates you want minimum, but detail says you want Max value.  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add the `max()` function.

```
Select selectedicao, selectedyear, selectedmonth, max(kfactor) as max_kfactor
From weatherdaily
Where Selectedyear = 1990 and selectedmonth = 1
Group By selectedicao, selectedyear, selectedmonth
```

Comment: Yes !, I thought the Group By fields had to exactly match the Select fields so I never tried it that way. THANKS